# How to send variable in text?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, nodemailer

I am able to send static email to fix mail id with fix content , how to make it dynamic in nodemailer .

```
transporter.sendMail({
    from: 'test@test.com',
    to: 'ashutosh.jha@mail.vinove.com',
    subject: 'Ashutosh Jha : credentials',
    text: 'hello how are you'
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working now thankyou

```
var mailcontent = ({
            from: 'test@test.com',
            to: email,
            subject: 'AJ : credentials',
            html: 'Dear '+docs[0]['name'] + ',<br/><br/>here is your credentials : <br/><br/><br/><b> username :'+docs[0]['username']+'<br/> password : '+docs[0]['password']+'</b><br/><br/> Thanks and regards , <br/>      AJ'
            });

            transporter.sendMail(mailcontent , function(err , success){
                if(err)
                {

                    res.render('forget-password',{
                    error : err
                    });     

                }else {
                    res.render('index',{
                    success : 'Information succesfully sent to "' + email+'"'
                    });     
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

A few options.

```
var body = 'Hello ' + name + ', how are you?';

var sprintf = require('sprintf-js').sprintf;
var body2 = sprintf('Hello %s, how are you?', name);
```

Or you could use a template engine like [Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/) or [HandleBars](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js).

Comment: how to add variables in text field ?

Comment: you can use the native node module [`util.format`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_format_format) for printf functionality as well